# Is it safe to use ROWID to locate a Row/Record in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm looking at a client application which retrieves several columns including `ROWID`, and 
later uses `ROWID` to identify rows it needs to update:

```
update some_table t set col1=value1
where t.rowid = :selected_rowid
```

Is it safe to do so?  As the table is being modified, can `ROWID` of a row change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"From Oracle 8 the `ROWID` format and size changed from 8 to 10 bytes. Note that `ROWID`'s will change when you reorganize or export/import a table. In case of a partitioned table, it also changes if the row migrates from a partition to another one during an `UPDATE`."

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ROWID

I'd say no. This could be safe if for instance the application stores `ROWID` temporarily(say generating a list of select-able items, each identified with `ROWID`, but the list is routinely regenerated and not stored). But if `ROWID` is used in any persistent way it's not safe.

Comment: I wonder what about ROWID use inside the same TX then ..? (For completeness, if such a usage is guaranteed safe.)

Comment: If you select for update a row you can be sure that no-one else would be able to change its ROWID. I don't know if it can be the same when you use transaction-level read consistency without selecting for update

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you are using the `ROWID` a short period of time after you `SELECT` it, that the table is a standard heap-organized table, and that the DBA isn't doing something to the table (which is a reasonably safe assumption if the application is online), the `ROWID` will be stable.  It would be preferable to use the primary key but when the primary key isn't available, plenty of Oracle-developed tools and frameworks will use the `ROWID` for short periods of time.  It would not be safe if you intended to use the `ROWID` a long period of time after you `SELECT` it-- for example, if you allow users to edit data locally and then synchronize with the master database some arbitrary length of time later.

The `ROWID` is just a physical location of a row so anything that causes that location to change will change the `ROWID`.

- If you are using index-organized tables or partitioned tables, updates to the row can change where the row is physically located which will change the `ROWID`.
- If a row is deleted from a heap-organized table, a subsequent `INSERT` might insert data with completely different data that happens to use the same `ROWID` the deleted row previously had.
- Various administrative tasks can cause the `ROWID` to change.  Exporting and importing the table will change the `ROWID` for example, but so will doing something like the new-ish online shrink command.  These administrative tasks will not normally be done while the application is up, however, and will almost certainly not be done during the day.  But it could lead to problems if the application isn't shut down when a DBA does this sort of thing or if the application persists the data.

Over time, it has become more and more common for new features to introduce new possibilities for `ROWID`s to change.  Index-organized tables and the online shrink option, for example, are relatively new features.  In the future, it is likely that there will be more features that will involve the potential at least for a `ROWID` to change.

Of course, if we're being pedantic, it's also not safe to rely on the primary key.  It is perfectly possible that some other session comes along and updates the primary key of the row after you read it or that some other session deletes the row after you select it and inserts a new row with the same data and a different primary key.  In either case, it helps to have some local knowledge about what the applications using the database are actually supposed to be doing.  It would be extremely uncommon, for example, to allow updates to primary keys or to reuse primary keys so you can generally determine that it's safe to use a primary key.  Similarly, it is relatively common to conclude that given the way you're using partitioning or given the way you've defined the index in your index-organized table that updates won't actually change the `ROWID`.  If you know that the table is partitioned by the `LOAD_DATE`, for example, and that you never update the `LOAD_DATE`, you won't actually experience changes to the `ROWID` because of an update.  If you know that the table is index-organized but that you're not updating a column that is part of that index, the `ROWID` won't change on an `UPDATE`.

Comment: Wow, the first bulleted point makes me think: Why would one *ever* use a ROWID for identification? (Does it being used *inside* a TX change this stability in this case?) Doing so might then "just stop working" if someone decides on a different table implementation ..

Comment: @pst - Even within the same transaction (assuming the default read committed transaction isolation level), it is possible for the `ROWID` to change.  Another session could delete the row, insert a new row that happens to have the same `ROWID` and commit.  Another session could update a row causing the it to move within the index-organized table or to a new partition.  The same thing, though, applies to a primary key-- it is entirely possible for the primary key to change.  In either case, you can benefit from local knowledge about what is supposed to happen.

Answer (score 4):

I do not think it is safe to do so, in theory it will not change, that is of course until someone "accidentally" deletes something on the actual DB...

I would just use the PK makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Sounds like the ROWID is desired to be used in lieu of a proper (or compound) PK ^^

Comment: pst, sometimes your compound primary key is so large it doesn't make sense to search with it when there are alternatives.